# List of tables and figures but single for multiple lines

Tags: classicthesis

Have this part in my `thesis.cls` but would like to have the double spacing between lot/lof but single spacing for multiple lines of lot/lof.

```
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}

{\clearpage\@tochead{\listtablename}{Table}\doublespace\@starttoc{lot}}

\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}

{\clearpage\@tochead{\listfigurename}{Figure}\doublespace\@starttoc{lof}}
```

Comment: Do you use package `setspace`? Please complete your code snippet to be complable and show us which document class you use and which captures resulting with problems ...

Comment: Kurt, I basically don't have any problem. However, I would like to have single spacing for captures with multiple lines. I my thesis.cls, it says double spacing but does not convert back to single spacing for multiple lines.

Comment: try `{\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\listoffigures
\listoftables}`

Comment: Thanks so much Touhami. That worked like magic. You enoy the rest of your day. Thanks Kurt as well.

Comment: @user28251: Instead of deleting the other question with the some content you could have improved that one  (Yes, we can see deleted questions ;-))

Comment: I deleted for no reason. Am sorry if I did.

Comment: @HarishKumar done.

Answer (score 2):

What we need is extra vertical space between entries, changing  `\parskip` locally does the job.

```
{\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\listoffigures
\listoftables}
```